# Why `overflow-x: visible` not work when overflow-y is scroll

Tags: css

[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/vibrant-poincare-hgbfr?file=/src/styles.css)

Here is my code, I want show the 'pink content' complete, So I set `overflow-y: scroll` and `overflow-x: visible`, but the `overflow-x` is not work well

Is my usage incorrect, or do I still need to adjust the HTML structure?

Comment: Don't use `absolute` position

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your usage/syntax isn't incorrect, but it is unfortunately a specifically disallowed combination.

`overflow-x: visible` is only compatible with `overflow-y: visible` (and not with `scroll` as you're using).

Source: Mozilla [overflow-x](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow-x#values)